# Need some guideline to refactor my php code in OOP concept

Tags: php, oop

I wrote a wordpress plugin that works fine. However, it just works but there is no OOP here because at that time it was necessary to build something asap. I read some literature and found that php do not support multiple inheritance due to diamond problem.

**Current scenario:**

```
Flickr
--pic importer
----1. sql.php
----2. javascript.php
----3. call to show database contents

--photoset importer
----1. sql.php
----2. javascript.php
----3. call to show database contents
```

Here, I have created 2 class: `picImporter` and `photosetImporter`. Both classes share common contents from (`1. sql.php` and `2. javascript.php`) but point-3 (*implementation of showing database content* is differnt for them).

**So, my idea is:** I should create another class `Global` and `photosetImporter`, `picImporter` class should extend this class. In the Global class there should be an abstract class that child class must define. So the design becomes:

```
Class Global{
   //$sql comes sql.php,
   //$javacript comes javascript.php,
   abstract protected function showDatabaseContents();
}

Class picImporter extends Global{
    protected function showDatabaseContents() {
        //implementation using **$sql** from base
    }
}

Class photosetImporter extends Global{
    protected function showDatabaseContents() {
        //implementation using **$javascript** from base
    }
}
```

Before I proceed, I just want to know if I am on right track or not and further instruction if possible.

Thanks,
-S.

Comment: have you ever heard about `has-a/is-a` relationships/dependency injection/solid principles?

Comment: No. Can you guide me with some easy example? Wikipedia article seems daunting in first sight as I have no idea on it.

Comment: Just read and absorb at first.  It probably won't make sense until it's already in your head and you approach a new problem and these principles occur to you as the logical approach to solving it.

Comment: Yes, real world scenario is the best way to learn this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no particular "right" way to do what you're looking for (though there are wrong ways).  Hard to know what method I would use without understanding what your javascript class does.

Typically, I create a single global DB abstraction class (what I assume your sql class is) and just access it from the global scope wherever I need it.  Global scope isn't evil, especially for things like database access which aren't inherent to whatever other classes you're creating but are needed pretty much everywhere.  The same may be true for your javascript class.

That said, if you need this sort of abstraction to maintain a consistent design in your application, then I see no problem with what you're doing here, this seems like a logical approach.

If you're looking for what might be a best practice, run a search for "PHP design patterns", but in general my approach with PHP is to keep it simple and accessible.  That may mean using a design pattern, or it may mean a more basic approach, depending.

Comment: Javascrip.php just echo some necessary javascript funtions for front-end. Right now, I am more concerned about consistency and happy that thinking sql connection class in Global scope is not bad :-)

Comment: Trying to learn and implement these sorts of concepts all at once, if you're not familiar with things like design patterns or the above mentioned has-a/is-a & other concepts, can be like drinking from a firehose, and you're likely to do it poorly if you don't take the time to learn to do it right.  If your application is time sensitive, then go ahead and code it in ways that make sense to you.  But either use this project or create another that you can write and re-write as you learn more about these principles.

Comment: I read about design pattern in my bachelor course 4 years ago but forgot due to lack of practice. I will start now with some basic design patters found in ibm.com's article. Then I will examine "yes/no" for implementing each pattern in this case...I hope it doesn't matter I am right or wrong or the pattern verification yields yes/no but the practice of reading and thinking will help in upcoming days.

Thanks for your comment.